# Artemis client did not reconnect after master node restart

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have Artemis configuration (shared storage) with following ha-policy (for master and backup):

```xml
<ha-policy>
  <shared-store>
    <master>
      <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
    </master>
  </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

```xml
<ha-policy>
  <shared-store>
    <slave>
      <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
    </slave>
  </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

Client connection string:

```
(tcp://master:61616,tcp://backup:61616)?ha=true&retryInterval=1000&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.0&reconnectAttempts=10
```

At ~18:38 the server crashed, then at ~18:48 it recovered.

Some applications were unable to reconnect correctly without restarting with following errors...

**APP 1**

Master node crash:

```
2020-08-06 18:38:37,873 [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] WARN org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
```

Master Node now active (the backup went into passive mode):

```
2020-08-06 18:47:50,949 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] WARN org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
```

Why? Other applications reconnected correctly

```
2020-08-06 18:47:59,994 [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] WARN org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client - AMQ212005: Tried 10 times to connect. Now giving up on reconnecting it.
```

```
2020-08-06 18:47:59,998 [Camel (camel-1) thread #4 - JmsConsumer[xxx]] WARN org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx' - trying to recover. Cause: Session is closed
2020-08-06 18:47:59,999 [Camel (camel-1) thread #4 - JmsConsumer[xxx]] INFO org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
2020-08-06 18:48:00,006 [Camel (camel-1) thread #3 - JmsConsumer[xxx]] WARN org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx' - trying to recover. Cause: Session is closed
```

This error this error was not fixed although the cluster was recovered:

```
2020-08-06 18:49:25,033 [Camel (camel-1) thread #5 - JmsConsumer[xxx]] INFO org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
2020-08-06 18:49:25,033 [Camel (camel-1) thread #7 - JmsConsumer[xxx]] WARN org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx' - trying to recover. Cause: AMQ119010: Connection is destroyed
```

**APP 2**

Master node crash:

```
2020-08-06 18:38:37.883  WARN 1 --- [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ212037: Connection failure to master/master:61616 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2020-08-06 18:38:46.935  WARN 1 --- [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ212005: Tried 10 times to connect. Now giving up on reconnecting it.
2020-08-06 18:38:46.939  WARN 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'yyyy' - trying to recover. Cause: Session is closed
2020-08-06 18:38:46.945  WARN 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'yyyy' - trying to recover. Cause: Session is closed
2020-08-06 18:38:46.963  INFO 1 --- [Thread-7] o.s.j.c.SingleConnectionFactory          : Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection

javax.jms.JMSException: ActiveMQDisconnectedException[errorType=DISCONNECTED message=AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection$JMSFailureListener.connectionFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:750) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection$JMSFailureListener.connectionFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:771) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.callSessionFailureListeners(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:704) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.failoverOrReconnect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:640) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.handleConnectionFailure(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:507) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.access$600(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:73) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingFailureListener.connectionFailed(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1229) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.protocol.AbstractRemotingConnection.callFailureListeners(AbstractRemotingConnection.java:77) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.fail(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:220) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.protocol.AbstractRemotingConnection.fail(AbstractRemotingConnection.java:220) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$CloseRunnable.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1018) ~[artemis-core-client-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) ~[artemis-commons-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) ~[artemis-commons-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) ~[artemis-commons-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.10.1.jar!/:2.10.1]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQDisconnectedException: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown
        ... 7 common frames omitted

2020-08-06 18:38:51.945  WARN 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'xxx' - trying to recover. Cause: AMQ219010: Connection is destroyed
2020-08-06 18:39:21.965 ERROR 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'yyyy' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
2020-08-06 18:39:52.983 ERROR 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'yyy' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
2020-08-06 18:40:23.992 ERROR 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'yyyy' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
```

Master Node now active (the backup went into passive mode):

```
2020-08-06 18:47:50.949  WARN 1 --- [Thread-5 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ212037: Connection failure to backup/backup:61616 has been detected: AMQ219015: The connection was disconnected because of server shutdown [code=DISCONNECTED]
2020-08-06 18:47:53.145 ERROR 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'yyyy' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=8, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
2020-08-06 18:47:53.146  WARN 1 --- [Thread-5 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ212004: Failed to connect to server.
```

This error this error was not fixed although the cluster was recovered:

```
2020-08-06 18:47:58.147 ERROR 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'yyyy' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=9, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=AMQ219024: Could not select a TransportConfiguration to create SessionFactory]
2020-08-06 18:48:53.160 ERROR 1 --- [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'yyyy' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=20, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=AMQ219024: Could not select a TransportConfiguration to create SessionFactory]
```

I tried to reproduce the error but could not. Maybe there are ideas for the correct setting?

Comment: It appears that you're using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1. Can you confirm this? If so, I recommend you move to 2.14.0. Also, keep in mind that since you're using Spring there are additional layers of connection retries aside from what you configure on the client's URL.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say, "Master Node now active (the backup went into passive mode)"? Do you mean that when the master went down the backup became active and then when the master came back up it initiated a fail-back which caused the backup to restart and the master to takeover?

Comment: Yes, i use  2.10.1. Is it enough to update the client? The server will be more difficult to update.

Comment: I mean when master came back then all clients reconnected to master (I see connections to the master in the master admin console and do not see connections in the backup admin console

Comment: I would update both the clients and the broker. There have been 4 releases since 2.10.1 so it's pretty old at this point. Generally speaking free community support is easiest to get on the latest release. Fewer people are willing to help on older releases.

Comment: I added slave config in question, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219428/discussion-between-wi-al-and-justin-bertram).